# How to run java without compilation

Tags: java

In order to speed up coding and testing I'm interested is there a way to run Spring Boot application in Wildfly without compilation?

for example can I deploy the application as exploded package?

Comment: Without compilation or without packaging?

Comment: Without compilation.

Comment: In that case, I don't think so

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: you should use [spring tool suite + wildfly](http://doraprojects.net/blog/?p=3307) to speed up your development cycles

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I think you are looking for [JSHELL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-465BA4F5-E77D-456F-BCB7-D826AC1E18AE). its REPL for java.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run java without compilation

There is no way.

> For example can I deploy the application as exploded package?

If you deploy an application as an exploded package of source files (".java"), they won't run.  The container won't compile them.

To deploy it an exploded package of ".class" files, you first need to compile the source code.

Basically, you cannot avoid compilation.

---

One way to reduce build / deploy cycle times is to use hot deployment; see [Hot-deploy Java classes and assets in Wildfly 8/9/10](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2017/10/27/hot-deploy-java-classes-and-assets-in)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you **can run only a single file with java 11+** https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-file-source-code

In order to **reduce compilation time** for **Spring Boot** you can use Gradle build server
https://medium.com/@cesarmcferreira/using-gradle-build-cache-server-73d7680baf2a